# Mapstruct does not automatically map the base type constructor

Tags: java, mapstruct

environment:
java: 17.0.1
mapstruct: 1.4.2.Final

example:

```java
public record RecordId(Long id) {
}
```

mapper

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface RecordIdAssembler {

    @Mapping(target = "id")
    RecordId convertRecord(Long id);

    @Mapping(source = "id",target = ".")
    Long convertRecord(RecordId id);

    List<RecordId> convertRecord(List<Long> id);
}
```

But compile with error

```
java: Ambiguous constructors found for creating java.lang.Long. Either declare parameterless constructor or annotate the default constructor with an annotation named @Default.
```

I can't modify the constructor of the Long type

How should I config it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not dealing with a mapping here, but with a container object (an object containing a single field). It is better to manually implement this, the list mappings are possible with mapstruct.

```java
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface RecordIdAssembler {
    default RecordId convertRecord(Long id) {
        return new RecordId(id);
    }

    default Long convertRecord(RecordId id) {
        return id.id();
    }
    List<RecordId> convertToRecord(List<Long> id);
    List<Long> convertFromRecord(List<RecordId> id);
}
```

an other option is to handle this where you have `RecordId` and `Long` as fields and convert them with mappings. For example in the following situation:

```java
class RecordDto {
  private Long id;
// other fields
// getters & setters
}
class RecordEntity {
  private RecordId recId;
// other fields
// getters & setters
}
@Mapper
interface RecordMapper {
  @Mapping(source = "id", target = "recId.id");
  RecordEntity map(RecordDto dto);

  @InheritInverseConfiguration
  RecordDto map(RecordEntity entity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think the first option is more appropriate and easy to reuse